# Azure Active Directory into existing Xamarin.Forms App

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin.forms, azure-active-directory

I currently want to apply a user authentication system using AAD into a Xamarin.Forms App I have been working on through Visual Studio. I have created an Azure account and the Xamarin support guides are out of date with the Azure WebPortal so just look for some help on implementing Azure Active Directory into my app, as to how to register my app to the AAD on the web portal, the proper NuGet packages, etc. at least to get me started. A lot of the online guides are outdated.

Answer (score 0):

Please use https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/3.13.8

The code samples are available at https://github.com/Azure-Samples?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=xamarin&type=&language=

Comment: thank you for your help, hopefully they update the portal navigation because it is still out of date